# Possible ambiguity in "In addition to the 3 main reasons, there is a 4th reason that has not been widely cited"

Tags: sentence-meaning, ambiguity, attachment-ambiguity

I am wondering if my sentence is ambiguous.

> In addition to the three main arguments, there is a fourth argument that, although important, has not been widely cited.

The "three main arguments" are extensively discussed by experts in the field. But the fourth argument that I am making is poorly cited (meaning that only a few people have mentioned this in passing).

Does my sentence in any way imply or sound like this:

> in addition to the three main not-widely-cited arguments, there is a fourth one ?

The reason I am having this feeling is because of "In addition to" — I feel this is perhaps making it sound like the three main arguments are also not widely cited.

Well, I think my reader would know what I mean because I have given lots of citations on the first three (and only one for the fourth). But I still wonder if my sentence is technically ambiguous or incorrect. On its own, is the sentence flawed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not ambiguous at all. The relative clause attaches to "a fourth argument" and clearly modifies it.

Technically the sentence doesn't say if the first three arguments have been widely cited or not. This is not really an ambiguity, just missing information.